# Coverage color meaning in eclipse

Tags: java, testing, code-coverage

I have source code (java language) in eclipse. Then I check the coverage. I give 4 as the input. But I don't know what's the meaning of the color (red, yellow, and green). This is the code(ifElse.java):

[image: code coverage in eclipse]

Then what's the meaning of Statement 80%, Branch 50%, and Term 50%? How to calculate it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

Green means your tests have run through those instructions.

Yellow means your tests have run through those instructions, but not all of possible cases have been covered.

If you have this simple conditional:

```
if(i>2) <- yellow
```

It means your tests covered a value of `i` either less than 2 or greater than two, but not two of them. In such case you must to think of 2 different "scenarios" which usually means two different tests.

Red means none of your tests reached those instructions.

Comment: So, how to calculate the percentage of statement, branch, and term? And what are the meaning of them?

Comment: Statement is the number of 'instructions' that were covered(basically the green ones)
Branch is the coverage of cases in an if statement. In my example, if you only tested for values greater than 2, it means you left one possible scenario out, which is 50%.
I'm not sure about the Term...

Comment: How about if(angka%2==0)? Is that also a statement?

Answer (score 1):

Here is something you may find useful.

**Green** is for fully covered lines of code,

**Yellow** is for partly covered lines i.e. There may be some branches that missed to reach) and

**Red** is for lines that have not been executed at all.

Apart from these addition colored diamond are also shown and they have same meaning as above.

[Source: EclEmma](https://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/annotations.html)